# IBOutlets in subview are nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5

I have a `UIViewController`,which is associated with custom class `MAViewControllerMenu` and loads right after the splash screen. In that `UIViewController`, I have an `UIScrollView`, which belongs to another class, `MASlideShowView`, in which the IBOutlet of the `UIScrollView` is defined and is connected to.

[image]

The class for the UIViewController has, among others, the field:

```
@property MASlideShowView* slideShow;
```

as a private property for the class that holds the UIScrollView inside it.

Also in the `UIViewController`,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//TODO    [_slideShow initializeImages];
    _slideShow = [[MASlideShowView alloc] initWithModel];
    _slideShow.delegate = imageViewController;

}

- (void)viewDidAppear{
    [super viewDidAppear:(YES)];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     // Set up the content size of the scroll view
     //HERE, self.slideShow is allocated, but all the fields it has, including the IBOutlet to the UIScrollView is still nil
    CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.slideShow.frame.size;
    _slideShow.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.pageViews.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);

    //Delegate
    _slideShow.scrollView.delegate = self;

    // Load the initial set of pages that are on screen
    [_slideShow loadVisiblePages:YES page_index:0 image:_last_image_taken];
```

}

Note the error I saw in the comments in the above class

The `MASlideShowView` file looks like:

h:

```
@class MASlideShowView;
@protocol slideShowDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)imageViewSelected:(MASlideShowView*)slideShow image:(UIImage*)image;

@end

@interface MASlideShowView : UIScrollView

@property (nonatomic,weak) id<slideShowDelegate> delegate;//delegate to next controller to notify upon picture centered
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *rotateImageButton;
@property UIImageView* centered_image_view;
- (IBAction)PageThroughPageControl;
- (IBAction)rotateImageButtonClicked;

- (id)initWithModel;
- (void)pageThroughPageControl;
- (void)addImageToSlideshow:(UIImage*)toAdd;
- (void)loadVisiblePages:(BOOL)use_page_number page_index:(NSInteger)page image:(UIImage*)image;
@end
```

m:

```
- (id)initWithModel{    
    [self initializeImages];    
    return self;
}

-(void)initializeImages{

    // Set up the image you want to scroll & zoom and add it to the scroll view
    self.pageViews = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    NSInteger pageCount = 0;
    _imageViewCount = 0;

    // Set up the page control
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount;

    // Set up the array to hold the views for each page
    self.pageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pageCount; ++i) {
        [self.pageViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}
```

My question is simple:

How can I make the `UIScrollView` initialize? 
I know that there's no `viewDidAppear` as it inherits from `UIScrollView`.

Thanks

Comment: _slideShow = [[MASlideShowView alloc] initWithModel]; I think you dont need to init a MASlideshowView, because when your parentView is MAViewControllerMenu loads Xib, also loads other subview in xib file. So, your slideShow is still exist, dont need to alloc or init. If you want to initialize UIScrollView. In your MASlideShowView implement a awakeFromNib method.

Comment: @HoanNguyen - Solved!! It turns out that my IBOutlet scrollView in MASlideShowView is indeed initialized. However, I had a problem connecting the RIGHT instance of MASlideShowView (the one that holds the initialized value of scrollView) to my _slideShow property in my main UIViewController's class, MAViewControllerMenu. You were completely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Interface Builder, I would recommend calling `initializeImages` inside `awakeFromNib`:

> An awakeFromNib message is sent to each object loaded from the
>   archive, but only if it can respond to the message, and only after all
>   the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized. When an
>   object receives an awakeFromNib message, it is guaranteed to have all
>   its outlet instance variables set.

More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Other observations:

As for your code, you have `slideShow` correctly set by Interface Builder when entering `viewDidLoad` but you're replacing that instance by assigning `_slideShow = [[MASlideShowView alloc] initWithModel]`, which results in a completely different object.

Moreover your `initWithModel` doesn't look at all like a correct `init` method as it doesn't call any of its `super`'s `init` methods. You should start with Apple's snippet by writing `init` in an empty line and press escape:

[image]

[image]

Again the first paragraph of the answer should be enough for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you could go about fixing this.

One way is like @HoanNguyen mentioned to use awakeFromNib. Personally I don't use this but it's a valid lifecycle event for setup.

Another option is to override initWithCoder: which is the standard initializer storyboards use

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initializeImages];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You could then remove your initWithModel call and the storyboard should handle everything.

Comment: I tried using that function, but it doesn't compile the super call. My 'MASlideShowView' inherits from UIScrollView, and doesn't seem to have 'initWithCoder'

Comment: Hmmm alright, then you probably should use either awakeFromNib, or you could try overriding standard initializers for UIView which is initWithFrame